# How can I convert the unsafe characters in a relative file name into a safe version using the Jersey UriBuilder?

Tags: java, file, path, jersey, uri

I have two strings.  One names a folder's absolute (or relative) path.  The other names a file name with potentially unsafe characters:

```
String folder = "C:\a\b\c\dir";

Sting file = "file name: contains-unsafe_characters?" + ".txt"
```

I want to smash these to strings together literally in the form:

```
String absPath = folder + SYSTEM_INDEPENDENT_PATH_SEPERATOR + convertToPercentOctal(folder);
```

Now, there are probably one million approaches to try to do this:

```
UriBuilder folderBuilder = UriBuilder.fromPath(folder);
UriBuilder fileBuilder   = UriBuilder.fromPath(file);
URI completeFileName = folderBuilder.build().resolve(fileBuilder.build());
```

or:

```
URI completeFileName = UriBuilder.fromPath(folder).path(file).build();
```

etc.

The first block of code fails because there may be a **:** in the file name.  If that is the case, UriBuilder will try to parse it as the optional *scheme:*.  The second way fails because it returns the first and second half converted to %octal notation separated by a system *dependent* '/' character.

Is there a way concatenate a two strings, convert the result to a writable file name, and return a valid URI I can use to create the file?

Comment: This might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730009/validate-a-file-name-on-windows

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Sort of, thanks.. but it's for Windows.  I'm looking for a system independent method as Java is supposed mask system dependence (at least with writing to the file system)..