# jQuery using regex to check for valid filename

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a form that lets the user type what they want their filename with extension to be when downloading a file, but I need to validate on the client side (doesn't contain `[^/?*:;{}\\]+\\.[^/?*:;{}\\]+`, stuff like that).  The filename does not need to contain an extension, but can if they wish.  I found this : [Validate a file name on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730009/validate-a-file-name-on-windows)
But I am not fluent enough in jQuery to make it work.

Comment: This doesnt really have anything to do with jQuery perse, its a javascript issue. Here you go, MDN docs for regexp https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: I'd suggest using a white-list (rather than a blacklist) of characters you'd allow, it's a little easier to manage that way.

Comment: @DavidThomas any reasonable file system has a blacklist, not a whitelist. Some don't even have either. Linux will let you insert control characters into the file name if the file system supports that.

Comment: @Jan: I didn't say that's how it's most-often implemented in file systems, but I do believe that for validation purposes a white-list is easier to manage. But, of course, it's a personal choice and both approaches are (to my mind at least) perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment stated its not a jQuery issue its a javascript thing you're after.

You can go two ways, the easiest being

```
var myString = "hello world";
var regexp = /w+/
var match = regexp.exec(myString);
console.log(myString); //will print the world "hello"
```

The other would be using the `Regexp Object`.

Simply instead of using "literal regexp", if you would agree to call it that, use the object

```
var re = new RegExp("\\w+");
var match = re.exec(myString);
console.log(myString); //will print the world "hello"
```

This handy website is primary for Ruby regexp but its a great tool of creating regexps

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: `/w+/` (contains a word character) is not a good criterion for valid file names.

Comment: True, but I wasn't aiming for a complete solution but a pointer in the right direction, but I can edit my answer.

Comment: I didn't use this answer completely, but like limelights said i used to to direct me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code for this. This return the file names if valid. else it will return **null**

```
var filename = ''; // enter your file name here
alert(filename.match(/^\s*[a-z-._\d,\s]+\s*$/i))
```

If you want to exclude some characters mention those chars inside the square brackets as shown below

```
/^[^<>%$]*$/
```

Comment: `příliš žluťoučký kůň.texťák` is not valid file name in your opinion? My file system (NTFS@W7) begs to differ :-)

Comment: that looks like a made up language... ;)

Comment: @limelights I think the same about Hungarian :-) see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pangrams#Czech to verify it's a real language :-)

Comment: @limelights "Jó foxim és don Quijote húszwattos lámpánál ülve egy pár bűvös cipőt készít." -- "My good foxterrier and don Quixote are making a pair of magic shoes by a 20-watt lamp." in Hungarian :-)

Comment: Edited my code. If you just want to mention some characters to exclude you can use something as mentioned in my answer.