# How can I check if a string is a valid file name for windows using R?

Tags: windows, r, filenames

I've been writing a program in R that outputs randomization schemes for a research project I'm working on with a few other people this summer, and I'm done with the majority of it, except for one feature. Part of what I've been doing is making it really user friendly, so that the program will prompt the user for certain pieces of information, and therefore know what needs to be randomized. I have it set up to check every piece of user input to make sure it's a valid input, and give an error message/prompt the user again if it's not. The only thing I can't quite figure out is how to get it to check whether or not the file name for the .csv output is valid. Does anyone know if there is a way to get R to check if a string makes a valid windows file name? Thanks!

Comment: Try to create the file. If it succeeds, you are good to go. If it fails, you are not.

Comment: Two possibilities: Error handling (using `try`/`tryCatch`) as suggested by @DavidHeffernan. Or be very restrictive and allow only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: The rules are given here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx but I think it's better to ask for forgiveness than permission in this scenario

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that the easiest way to make sure a filename is valid is to use [`fs::path_sanitize()`](https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/path_sanitize.html).

It removes control characters, reserved characters, and Windows-reserved filenames, truncating the string at 255 bytes in length.

Answer (score 1):

These characters aren't allowed: `/\:*?"<>|`.  So warn the user if it contains any of those.

Some other names are also disallowed: `COM`, `AUX`, `NUL`, `COM1` to `COM9`, `LPT1` to `LPT9`.

You probably want to check that the filename is valid using a regular expression.  See this other answer for a Java example that should take minimal tweaking to work in R.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6804755/134830

You may also want to check the filename length (260 characters for maximum portability, though longer names are allowed on some systems).

Finally, in R, if you try to create a file in a directory that doesn't exist, it will still fail, so you need to split the name up into the filename and directory name (using `basename` and `dirname`) and try to create the directory first, if necessary.

That said, David Heffernan gives good advice in his comment to let Windows do the wok in deciding whether or not it can create the file: you don't want to erroneously tell the user that a filename is invalid.

You want something a little like this:

```
nice_file_create <- function(filename)
{
  directory_name <- dirname(filename)
  if(!file.exists(directory_name))
  {
    ok <- dir.create(directory_name)
    if(!ok)
    {
      warning("The directory of that path could not be created.")
      return(invisible())
    }
  }
  tryCatch(
    file.create(filename),
    error = function(e)
    {
      warning("The file could not be created.")
    }
  )
}
```

But test it thoroughly first!  There are all sorts of edge cases where things can fall over: try UNC network path names, "~", and paths with "." and ".." in them.