# Java and "&" in file names

Tags: java, file, io

We have existing files with "&" in file names and want to use `java.io.File`, 
for instance the method `list()`. In this case, list doesn't return the directory entries. Escaping "&" with "\&" doesn't help. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893977/java-how-to-find-out-whether-a-file-name-is-valid

Comment: Please list a small but runnable code snippet showing the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me on Mac OSX.  Please post your code illustrating the problem.

```
$ touch a\&b
$ touch c\ \&b
$ ls
a&b  c &b
$ scala
scala> import java.io.File
import java.io.File

scala> new File(".").list()
res0: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(a&b, c &b)
```