# how to detect a pasting of file in JAVA

Tags: java, filepath

I am able to detect how to get path of file which is in clipboard, but how can i detect a paste of file, Like 
If i paste a file/folder in D drive, then java should detect as

```
D:\\Filename.jpg
```

Comment: You want to [Watch a Directory for Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: Is the user pasting his file through your application? Or are you trying to build a software that will monitor his file system?

Comment: I want to monitor

Comment: have used this one some years ago: https://dzone.com/articles/how-watch-file-system-changes

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: whenever **something** gets pasted, you could try to use that string as filename, and see if that works.

As outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java) for example.

In other words: if you find that some string represents a file name, then its a file. If not, then not. That would be to figure if the string denotes an existing file.

Beyond that, you could check if the string *could* be a *valid* file name. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893977/java-how-to-find-out-whether-a-file-name-is-valid) for that option.

And finally, if you are talking about a true **file** being **dropped** into a file system folder, then you have to learn how to create a **watch** service that keeps watching the file system (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494869/file-changed-listener-in-java) for that).