# php file upload to the server

Tags: php, security, file-upload

Writing a secure file upload PHP Script from the bottom sounds like hell to me.

The basic rules to uploading a file in no particular order:

1) Create a new file, something random, and give the new uploaded file that name

2) Check the extension

3) Check for the exif trick

4) Store all uploaded files off the web root, and give that directory no permissions to execute files.

5) make sure that the file upload function is PHP does not execute the code while uploading the file

6) Check the file size

7) Do some malware scan

8) limit filesize

So i am thinking thats a lot :)

I havent even begun writing a script for all this, because i have 3 basic questions.

1) Is my list complete, if something are missing please state which

2) is there some sort of framework that can do all this for me? Something simple, not a big huge one that can do multible other things.

3)
Is this a guide good?
http://www.sitepoint.com/file-uploads-with-php/

I would love to post code, but since this subject is big, i feel its better to ask larger.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont think that this is "HUGE" when you are converting it to code. However #7 is little bit complicated when compared to others.

Comment: I can't think of anything else you could possibly do, this list is pretty exhaustive.

Comment: @Red Yea you are right ;)  thanks for both of your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “exif trick” and other measures in that article to sniff file contents are of little use in themselves. (OK, it's worth checking uploaded images are of the expected pixel size, but that's application-specific rather than a security problem.)

The article doesn't say what the threat model is that it's trying to address with filetype sniffing, but what this is commonly trying to do is prevent cross-site scripting attacks, where the attacker includes some active content in the file. Usually this is with HTML in files, which browsers (especially IE) sniff and decide to interpret as HTML even though that's not how the file is being served. Unfortunately, checking that a file begins with a PDF header, or represents a valid GIF image does not help you here because it's possible to make “chameleon” files that can be interpreted as different filetypes simultaneously.

This attack can be blocked in modern browsers by serving the files with a specific non-HTML `Content-Type` and an `X-Content-Type: nosniff` header. However there are more obscure attacks involving getting content into Flash or Java plugins that are not affected by this header, and it's not watertight against older browsers.

The really-safe way to stop XSS attacks on uploaded files is simply to serve them from a different hostname (ideally, a different domain name and IP address, but a simple subdomain is at least mostly-effective). Then you can let an attacker XSS the user-uploads-hosting site as much as they like without it having a negative effect on your main site.

Virus scanning is unlikely to prove useful for general-purpose file upload functions. If you are expecting people to use the site to exchange Windows executables then it can be worth scanning those for traditional malware, but for the general case you're typically concerned about attacks against the website itself—server exploitation, XSS, browser exploits—and those kind of attacks are not detected by AV scanners.

Your step (1) of creating a new random filename is a much better approach than “sanitising” user-supplied filenames as the linked article tries to do. Its “safe filename” function is not directly vulnerable to directory traversal, but it does still allow oddnesses like `..` (on its own), the empty string, `.htaccess`, and filenames that would confuse a Windows server, like trailing dots, [reserved names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122400/what-are-reserved-filenames-for-various-platforms) and over-long names.

You are right that secure file upload is much trickier than it initially seems, and unfortunately most tutorial code out there (especially for PHP) is pretty disastrous.

Comment: Super post :)  I think what you are saying is very interesting and that i need to re-visit my thought center before i code that upload functionality.  I think the ideal approach to my problem is to use some sort of framework, maybe Zend will have something fancy that i can use.  To me it seems like that uploading images to a subdomain will read/write rights only is the best solution to go for.