# FileChannel.tryLock causes java.io.IOException: Incorrect function

Tags: java, windows-7, io

What could be causing this? I have a Java program I wrote that works fine on my Windows 7 PC in Java 6u33 and Java 7u67, but on a coworker's PC running Java 7u67 under Windows 7, I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.io.IOException: Incorrect function
        at sun.nio.ch.FileKey.create(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileLockTable.newSharedFileLockTable(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.fileLockTable(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(Unknown Source)
```

I can't make heads or tails of what is actually causing this error and how I can fix it.

---

Hmm. Apparently this is Java wrapping an underlying OS error (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8025619). Any clue what causes an "Incorrect function" error in Windows?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but if you can run it fine on your machine using the same specs, maybe he has some kind of file corruption on his machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh. It actually had nothing to do with Java, and everything to do with reserved filenames under Windows.

I was trying to create a file of the form `COMnn.LOCK` and on my PC, I was using COM13.LOCK (a legal filename under Windows) but on my coworker's PC it was COM5.LOCK, which is apparently an illegal filename under Windows; any filename with COMn (where n is any 1 digit number)  and any extension is illegal. >:(

see [What are reserved filenames for various platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122400/what-are-reserved-filenames-for-various-platforms)

Comment: Well you must have succeeded in creating the file. The problem came when you tried to lock it.