# Call to REST BASED service with Parameter value "CON" fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am using rest based service to perform DML operations.

Here is my client:

```
var resourcePath = DeleteSubApplicationUri.Apply("AppCode", AppCode);
var DeleteSubAppuri = resourcePath.Apply("SubAppCode", SubAppCode);
result = await RefAppServers.RestClient.PostAsync < string, SaveDataMessage >(DeleteSubAppuri, SubAppCode);
```

For `AppCode` value `"CON"` , the call is not reaching the service. I had to change it to some other value (i.e. `"CNT"`) to get it working. But May I know why the value `"CON"` is not allowing the service from being called? Is there any special inbuilt meaning for CON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"CON"` is a reserved filename on Windows: if you try and create a file or folder with that name it will fail.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122400/67392) for a full list, and on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for all the details.

Comment: Ok  maybe because of this, my service is becoming irresponsive.