# File is not created in project

Tags: c

When I call the fopen function, it simply does nothing, when i open the project the file doesn't exist and it also does nothing within the program. What I'm trying to do in this function is delete something from a file, and I do this by ignoring the part that I want to delete and copying the rest in the "aux.bin" file, then copying that to the initial file

```
void stergereAngajat (char CNP[14])
{
    FILE* fin = fopen("angajati.bin", "rb+");
    FILE* fout = fopen("aux.bin", "wb+");
    Angajat a;
     while (fread(a.CNP, 14 * sizeof(char), 1, fin) == 1)
    {
        int nr;
        fread(&nr, sizeof(int), 1, fin);
        a.nume = (char*)malloc(nr * sizeof(char));
        fread(a.nume, nr * sizeof(char), 1, fin);
        fread(&a.varsta, sizeof(int), 1, fin);
        fread(&a.salariu, sizeof(int), 1, fin);
        if (strcmp(a.CNP, CNP) != 0)
        {
            fwrite(a.CNP, 14 * sizeof(char), 1, fout);
            fwrite(&nr, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
            fwrite(a.nume, nr * sizeof(char), 1, fout);
            fwrite(&a.varsta, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
            fwrite(&a.salariu, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
        }
    }
    fflush(fout);
    char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fout)) != EOF)
        fputc(c, fin);
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

}
```

Comment: You absolutely need to check the return value of `fopen`. If it is `NULL`, the file could not be opened for some reason and then it's pointless to `fread`/`fwrite` on it.

Comment: Yes, the file is NULL

Comment: But why is that?

Comment: The most common reasons are: 1. the file does not exist in the current directory. 2. You are not allowed to create a file in the current directory. What is your platform?

Comment: Windows 10, the problem seemed to be that the file was named "aux.bin" which when I tried to create it manually in the project told me it is a name reserved for Windows

Comment: Oh, yes of course. There are some weird names that are reserved (legacy from a time where you probably weren't born yet). These are `con`, `aux`, and a few other I don't remember.

Comment: More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122400/what-are-reserved-filenames-for-various-platforms

Comment: Just a side note  (i'm maybe wrong): Have you tried just with rb, without the +?

Comment: It doesn't work either, I guess it's just the name problem

Comment: The above code does not `rewind` either `fin` or `fout` before the loop that calls `fputc`. Also `char c` should be `int c` because `char` might not be able to represent the value `EOF`.