# How to use os.Open when no such file return err is nil

Tags: go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f := "D:\\cron"
    fmt.Println(os.Stat(f))
    fmt.Println(os.Open(f))

    f = "D:\\con"
    fmt.Println(os.Stat(f))
    fmt.Println(os.Open(f))
}

result：
<nil> CreateFile D:\cron: The system cannot find the file specified.
<nil> open D:\cron: The system cannot find the file specified.
<nil> CreateFile D:\con: The parameter is incorrect.
&{0xc000086a00} <nil>
```

I think when the file doesn't exist,os.Open should return err != nil
But I wonder why "D:\con" returns err == nil

Comment: Not *precisely* a duplicate, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/122400/1256452

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Windows by any chance? "con" is a reserved file name, a relic of the DOS days.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have checked. It's really a problem.

Comment: @janbar if this answer satisfies your question, then please accept it.