# Is "C:\nul" directed to any file or folder?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, nul

I used this code to create a filestream ,and I tried to output something by this filestream.

Here's my cpp code : (MinGW 9.2.1,Windows 10)

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("C:\\nul");
for(unsigned long long i=1llu;i<=18446744073709551615ull;++i)
    outfile<<i<<endl;
```

It ran for a few seconds and I use "Ctrl+C" to kill the progress, but it seem to be the available capacity of my C disk is smaller at runtime.
My description may not be accurate enough because of my poor English :(

Let me put it another way: I noticed that the remaining space of my C disk is about 0.2Gb less than before.

Is it output to my C disk?If so,where is it?

I am searching for a long time on Net.Please help give some ideas how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance !

---

Upd:

[There is my files on C disk.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFcaU.jpg)

I'm **really sure** that the remaining space of my C disk is much less than before.

Comment: @user7860670 ,I want to know where is it than I want to delete it.

Comment: `nul` is one of the [reserved names in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122400/what-are-reserved-filenames-for-various-platforms), you cannot really use it.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen ,so the data is not actually written to my disk,right?

Comment: I'm not sure honestly. You should first check if `outfile.is_open()` returns `true` and then if `outfile<<i<<endl;` returns `true`. I believe `nul` may work like `/dev/null` on Unix and just ignore the data that went there, but your observations seem to prove otherwise - perhaps the data went to Rubbish bin or the file is invisible under Windows Explorer.

Comment: Does not output to the console prove that it was opened it successfully?  @Yksisarvinen

Comment: I tried it just now,it returned true,but it seems that it doesn't work as expected. @Yksisarvinen

Comment: I have sloved this problem,even idk where the files are,but it becomes normal after restarting.Thx for your idea all the same !   @Yksisarvinen

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and then overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `ofstream outfile; outfile.open("C:\\nul");` to `ofstream outfile("C:\\nul");`.

Comment: I get it , thanks for your suggestion. @PeteBecker

Answer (score 0):

Oh,maybe it's really on my Disk,I think.

But after restarting my PC,these spaces have been released,the remaining space of my disk is back to before.